# Setting fonts to parts of modeline

Tags: emacs, fonts, themes, elisp, modeline

How can I use multiple fonts in the modeline? For example, If want it to look like

**Line**: 23 **Size**: 3000

with `Line` and `Size` in a different font than the `modeline` font, how should

```
(setq-default mode-line-format '(
    "Line: %l Size: %i"
))
```

be modified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `propertize`.  For example, to get `Line:` and `Size:` in bold as in your example:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format `(
    ,(propertize "Line:" 'face 'bold)
    " %l "
    ,(propertize "Size:" 'face 'bold)
    " %i"
))
```

You can use `M-x list-faces-display` to see samples of defined faces, or define your own.

For future reference, you can take a look at the documentation for any variable you're trying to customize with `C-h v`; the help for `mode-line-format` mentions using `propertize`.

Comment: Thanks. But your code does not work as is. I am looking at the documentation, and trying different versions without `,` before `(`, and with/without `:propertize` but that does not work either.

Comment: I wrote the code in Emacs; it works (http://sabi.net/temp/modeline.png).  Make sure you're using a backtick (`\``) not a quote (`'`).  The `:propertize` form has the problem with `risky-local-variable` as described in the documentation.

Comment: It worked. I didn't know the use of backtick, and had used a quote. That was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: How can I set part of it not the whole mode line, such as I only want to set the line:column part, not set the whole mode line into just the line:column????

Comment: Is it possible to propertize the `"%l"` and other special percent-sign variables?

Comment: Sure! You can put a `%l` or whatever inside `propertize` too.